# Wordpress issue with show in images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having some issues with images on my WordPress site. Im quite new to the wordpress-world.

The issue is that when I insert an image, a property is automaticly set "srcset", which make image to be shown as "broken". see the code bellow. However, If I enter the webbrowser inspection window and maually remove the srcset then the image is shown.

`<img src="https://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning.jpg" class="image wp-image-161  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" srcset="http://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning.jpg 500w, http://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning-300x32.jpg 300w, http://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning-115x12.jpg 115w, http://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning-64x7.jpg 64w" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, 500px" width="500" height="53">`

[image]

...and now I have manually removed the "srcset"-attribute in the inpection window.

`<img src="https://media1.babyful.se/2019/11/footer-logo-betalning.jpg" class="image wp-image-161  attachment-full size-full" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" width="500" height="53">`

[image]

Comment: This might be caused by some plugin. A good practice is to disable them one by one and see when the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, found the issue.

my website was using "https" while media-domain was using "http". So the website was not calling media-domain correctly.